# Cancelling dispatch_group_notify

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have an iOS application which in some cases creates multiple requests to a server to populate the screen. To speed things up, we have made the requests running concurrently. For that we have used dispatch_group_enter, dispatch_group_leave, and dispatch_group_notify to ensure the screen is not populated before all answers have been returned:

```
   performRequest1() // calls dispatch_group_enter before sending the request and dispatch_group_leave when receiving the response
   performRequest2() // calls dispatch_group_enter before sending the request and dispatch_group_leave when receiving the response
   dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       populateScreen()
   }
```

Our problem occurs when the user presses the back button before we have received a response from both server requests. In this case we have a setup that automatically cancels the request to the server (1), and my success/failure blocks are therefore not called (2). Therefore dispatch_group_leave is never called. I thought this would be fine (I do not want my populateScreen() method to be called anyway). But iOS seems to have [a bug](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2014/Apr/msg00483.html%E2%80%8B) that prevents a semaphore to be released before it has been returned to its initial state (3). In other words, I am forced to call dispatch_group_enter exactly the same number of times as dispatch_group_leave. Even in situations where I just want to skip and dealloc everything.

Since it will be a major overhaul of my application to get the "cancel" operation sent to the view controller (4) executing the above code, I would like to hear if anybody has some ideas for better alternatives for waiting until multiple requests have finished loading? Or is there a better way to use dispatch_group_enter/leave?

**Edit**

A few clarifying points (in response to @Rob Napier's answer):

(1) cancel is implemented using AFNetworkings built-in AFHTTPRequestOperation.cancel() function

(2) AFNetworking *does* of course call the failure block when sending the cancel operation. But in the legacy code that I work on, there is a networking layer that handles the cancel operation and therefore are not sending the failure on to the class performing the request. This is most likely the root of the error, as @Rob Napier suggests, but it takes a little courage to change this architectural design in a big app... :-| Therefore, I would prefer to have a solution, where I could instead "abort" the waiting populateScreen() call when the viewController is deallocated.

(3) I know this post refers to something a little bit different. Nevertheless the crash in our app causes Xcode to stop at a point which have exactly the same code as in that post:

```
       0x110bab17a <+61>:  jne    0x110bab19c               ; <+95>
       0x110bab17c <+63>:  leaq   0x189d0(%rip), %rcx       ; "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Use-after-free of dispatch_semaphore_t"
       0x110bab183 <+70>:  movq   %rcx, 0x23316(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
       0x110bab18a <+77>:  ud2    
       0x110bab18c <+79>:  leaq   0x18972(%rip), %rcx       ; "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Semaphore/group object deallocated while in use"
       0x110bab193 <+86>:  movq   %rcx, 0x23306(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
   ->  0x110bab19a <+93>:  ud2
```

And ok, it might not be a bug in iOS, but just a really annoying design decision ;-)

(4) This is a big simplification to not lay out the entire architecture of our application. To be more precise: We have a service layer which performs the networking requests and creates the model which is returned to the view controller :-)

Comment: What about usage NSOperationQueue. You can set the requests as tasks . an set the number of tasks which can be executed simultaneously and cancel when necessary. AFNetworking provides this implementation. Please have a look
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
It's called `AFHTTPRequestOperation`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I didn't realize that there might be a built-in feature in AFNetworking for that. I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 4):

First, this isn't a bug. The link you provide is discussing `dispatch_semaphore`, which is related but different. In that thread, they note that even *that* isn't a bug. The docs are clear: "A call to [dispatch_group_enter] must be balanced with a call to dispatch_group_leave." This is intended behavior.

> In this case we have a setup that automatically cancels the request to the server, and my success/failure blocks are therefore not called.

This is the mistake. Whatever you mean here by "cancel" should be generating a failure condition, causing the failure block to be called. For example, if you call `cancel` on a `NSURLSessionTask`, the delegate will receive an error. Your `performRequest()` needs to do the same. How are you implementing "cancel?"

This means `populateScreen()` will be called on cancellation. That should be fine, since your system must already be able to deal with request errors, and cancellation is just another kind of error.

As a separate issue, if the above code is in the view controller, it is probably in the wrong place. View controllers should not be making network calls and waiting for results. They should just observe their model. Whenever the model changes, then they should change. They should pass requests from the user to the model and let the model talk to the network. In this particular case, that may just move the issue from the view controller to the model so may not change things very much. But it means that the view controller should be able to deallocate before cancellation completes. That's important because a view controller should never have to be kept around after it's popped.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent elaborate answer. I have edited my question to include answers to your points. You are probably right, the root is that I do not send the cancel error to the service making the request. But I am hoping to find another solution where I do not have to retest my entire app for cancel operations ;-)